# Black screen on booting Ubuntu in dual boot. Windows working fine. No cursor on screen either

Tags: ubuntu, boot, dual-boot, boot-loader

I have a dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10. I have been using this setup smoothly for 3 years( used to be 18.04). Since last week my Ubuntu is just showing a black screen. I tried boot repair tool, didn't fix it. I then reinstalled 20.04 using a flash drive and it booted properly that time. And now I restarted my machine and on choosing Ubuntu in the Grub screen, I get a black screen again. I feel like I corrupted my partition or something since even reinstalling didn't help.

Laptop - Asus K501UW-AB78 with Nvidia 960M.

Edit : I installed Pop OS over Ubuntu now. worked fine first couple of times then I booted into Windows once and after that my Linux is giving me black screen again.

Boot repair summary - https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/CrGWh3WMHg/ (The tool said there were some errors it couldn't fix).

Edit : If I boot into Windows at least once, after that I get black screen in Linux. However Im able to boot into Linux properly by choosing the boot option from BIOS directly. I think when I boot into Windows it's messing something up in the BIOS.

Comment: Black screen issue is often after grub fixes that Boot-Repair can do. But post link to new copy of Summary Report from Boot-Repair. What brand/model system and what video card/chip? Did Windows update UEFI/BIOS? That can revert settings to defaults, so check those also.

Comment: @oldfred updated my question. How do I check if my Windows is messing with UEFI/BIOS?

Comment: You show two ESP on sda. You can have multiple FAT32 and often grub will even find & let you boot efi files from a second FAT32 partition, but UEFI really only wants one ESP per device. Remove boot/esp flags from sda7 which have POP!OS boot files. You are not showing Ubuntu but POP which uses systemD boot. Do not think Boot-Repair set up for repairing that as it reinstall grub. You need either nomodeset or nVidia driver installed.

Comment: I should have been more clear, I have now installed POP os over Ubuntu to see if that would fix things. I dont have Ubuntu anymore

Comment: Do not know POP as it uses systemD boot not grub2.